# Grunt clean with exceptions not working according to github ticket

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/issues/38), I should be able to use the standard negating globbing pattern `!` to negate paths when cleaning files using `grunt-contrib-clean`. Using the Grunt docs example:

```
{src: ['foo/*.js', '!foo/bar.js', 'foo/bar.js'], dest: ...}
```

I tried this:

```
clean: {
    userContent: {
        src: ['content', 'css', 'scss', '!scss/framework']
    }
}
```

But no matter what I do, `scss/framework` is deleted. How can I fix this syntax so that everything in `scss/` is deleted *except* the `framework` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manatax was on the right track, but it was a little more complex than that. I had to explicitly clean sub *files* (not the folder) and explicitly ignore sub *files*:

```
clean: {
    userContent: {
        src: ['content', 'css', 'scss/**/*.scss', '!scss/framework/*']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clean: {
    userContent: {
        src: ['content', 'css', '!scss/framework', '!scss/framework/**/*']
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using 'files'?

Comment: Ah, removing the catch-all `'scss'` worked though! `src: ['content', 'css', 'scss/**/*.scss', '!scss/framework/*']` If you update your answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I understand, but you will not be cleaning anything else in scss if you remove the folder.

Comment: See my example in ^ comment.